# Использование табов дважды на странице

Tags: jquery, tabs

Использую следующий код для табов

```
    (function($){
    jQuery.fn.lightTabs = function(options){

        var createTabs = function(){
            tabs = this;
            i = 0;

            showPage = function(i){
                $(tabs).children("div").children("div").hide();
                $(tabs).children("div").children("div").eq(i).show();
                $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").removeClass("active");
                $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").eq(i).addClass("active");
            }

            showPage(0);

            $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").each(function(index, element){
                $(element).attr("data-page", i);
                i++;
            });

            $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").click(function(){
                showPage(parseInt($(this).attr("data-page")));
            });
        };
        return this.each(createTabs);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Но если они встречаются дважды на странице, срабатывает только последний из них, при чем даже при клике на вкладке в первом блоке.
Как исправить?

Пример на jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pnry0102/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, передавать в showPage указатель на таб

```
(function($){               
    jQuery.fn.lightTabs = function(options){

        var createTabs = function(){
            tabs = this;
            i = 0;

            showPage = function(tabs, i){
                $(tabs).children("div").children("div").hide();
                $(tabs).children("div").children("div").eq(i).show();
                $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").removeClass("active");
                $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").eq(i).addClass("active");
            }

            showPage(tabs, 0);              

            $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").each(function(index, element){
                $(element).attr("data-page", i);
                i++;                        
            });

            $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").click(function(){
                showPage($(this).parent().parent(), parseInt($(this).attr("data-page")));
            });             
        };      
        return this.each(createTabs);
    };  
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabs").lightTabs();
});
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/tm8sad7w/